# How to read .ENV values in Karate

Tags: karate

I'd like to remove secrets from my karate-config.js and place them in a .ENV file (which is in the .gitignore). That way I can run the Karate tests on various environments (local and Azure Devops pipelines) and only have to set the right environment variables.

The only thing is that I can't find a way to read the properties set in the .ENV file. `java.lang.System.getenv('MY_KEY')` returns null, while `java.lang.System.getenv('PATH')` does return the expected data.

Currently I've created a karate-base.js and merge in a secrets.js via a `karate.merge('secrets.js)`, but that's sub-optimal because I still need a file with secrets (passwords/keys) which I want to eliminate.